# "Мораль" и "нравственность" - это синонимы или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы

Может быть, глупый вопрос, но "мораль" и "нравственность" - синонимы или нет? Можно сказать "высшие ценности - это мораль и нравственность" или это будет тавтология?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*МОРАЛЬ, -и; ж. [франц. morale от лат. moralis - нравственный]
~1. Совокупность принципов и норм поведения людей по отношению друг к другу и к обществу; нравственность. Общечеловеческая м. Христианская, средневековая м. М. нового времени. Придерживаться какой-л. морали. Отвергать, опровергать требования морали.
~2. Нравственный вывод, урок из чего-л. М. басни. Найти м. в чьем-л. рассказе.
~3. Разг. Нравоучение, наставление. Читать м. Устать от моралей. < Моральный;  моралистический (см.).

НРАВСТВЕННОСТЬ, -и; ж. 
~1. Внутренние (духовные и душевные) качества человека, основанные на идеалах добра, справедливости, долга, чести и т.п., которые проявляются в отношении к людям и природе. Человек высокой, безупречной нравственности. Развитие нравственности. Требования нравственности. Слабые, жалкие представления о нравственности. Упадок нравственности. 
~2. Совокупность норм, правил поведения человека в обществе и природе, определяемые этими качествами. Законы, кодекс, нормы нравственности.*
© БТС(Кузнецов)

Т.е. в первом значении мораль - почти полный синоним нравственности.
Есть, правда, некоторые стилистические особенности. "Нравственность" - почти всегда с положительным значением, а "мораль" может быть и с осуждением, если эта мораль неприемлема говорящему.

> > > Можно сказать "высшие ценности - это мораль и нравственность" или это будет тавтология?

Ну это от автора зависит. Я бы постерегся. Дейстительно смахивает на тавтологию.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не синонимы. Но тем не менее так лучше не говорить. Не из-за тавтологии, а по другой причине. Дело в том, что нравственность - это совокупность внутренних установок человека, опирающихся на его представления о добре и зле, а мораль - это набор внешних требований к поведению человека со стороны социума. Разница примерно такая же, как между словами "этика" и "этикет". Мораль никак не связана с понятиями "добро" и "зло". Она формируется, исходя из стремления к общественной пользе. Например, убийство человека - это безнравственный поступок, но не обязательно аморальный. В некоторых культурах наличие мотива кровной мести полностью оправдывает убийцу в глазах общества. А вот поездка голым на метро - это поступок аморальный. Его никак нельзя назвать безнравственным, поскольку он не имеет никакого отношения к добру и злу. В некотором смысле мораль - это протез нравственности. Приведённая вами фраза аналогична заявлению: "Наши ценности - это натуральные ноги и протезы". Утверждение как бы подразумевает, что ноги и протезы имеют для нас одинаковую ценность, хотя вряд ли это так. Скорее всего, подлинной ценностью являются только ноги, а ценность протезов сугубо вторична и состоит в том, что они имитируют ноги. С моралью и нравственностью примерно то же самое, поэтому лучше говорить как-нибудь более обтекаемо. Например: "Морально-нравственные нормы - это наш высший приоритет". Если не называть вещи ценностями, то вопрос об их приоритете относительно друг друга может и не возникнуть. При таком сложносоставном написании через дефис вроде как подразумевается, что это один набор норм. Просто он очень широкий и всеохватный. В него входят как нормативные представления о добре и зле, так и правила общественного поведения.